# How to combine unicode characters?

Tags: java, android, unicode

Say I have a character "a" which I need to combine with a symbol ( ̌  ) which I have in form of a hex value "030c".

What do you think would be the best way to combine them?

**P.S.
Thanks, "a\u030c" does give â in logcat, but on android itself, it just shows a blank square. Is there a way to fix it without having the users to install additional fonts?**

Comment: I guess you need a lookup table for character with symbol combinations. Because there is afaik no deterministic way to get `'a' + '"' = 'ä'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"a\u030c" or "\u01ce", the latter being the a-caron ǎ.
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting that android does give "ǎ" with "\u01ce" , yes gives a blank square with "a\u030c".

Comment: The used font probably misses U+030C, the combining diacritical caron. In general you can with java.text.Normalizer convert between the two forms.

Comment: The Android fonts all lack the combining caron (U+030C) but include the letter a with caron (U+01CE). The latter, and precomposed characters in general, usually work better than combining diacritic marks. They are more often present in fonts, and they tend to produce typographically better results (a glyph designed by a typographer vs. an algorithmically produced combination of a base letter and a diacritic mark).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean string literal, then

```
String str = "a\u030c";
```

Comment: Yes, seems to work! Thanks! P.S. Ooops, it does appear in LogCat fine, but on android just like an empty square...

Answer (score 1):

You should not hard-code your own mapping tables.

What you need is this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html